# Where are Gallery's applied image effects stored?

Tags: android

If I have a uri of an image, how can I find out which filters have been applied via the Gallery app? Right now if I retrieve a bitmap from the uri, it doesn't show any of the effects.

Comment: What makes you think that all "gallery" apps even offer such filters, let alone apply them in some permanent fashion?

Comment: I must have worded something wrong. When you click on 'Gallery', you can select an image and click 'edit'. Then you can apply several filters. Now, when accessing that image from its Uri, it doesn't include the filters that 'Gallery' has applied.

Comment: There are thousands of Android device models, containing dozens, if not hundreds, of distinct apps that might be considered a "gallery". Then there are the hundreds of Android apps available on the Play Store and elsewhere that implement "gallery"-type functionality. There is no requirement that any of these apps implement any sort of filters. There is no requirement that those that do offer filters publicize information about those filters to third-party apps. There is no requirement that those that do offer filters permanently modify the images. And so on.

Comment: I am not referring to any of those third-party gallery apps. I am talking about the pre-installed app called "Gallery". It looks like a black frame around a purple image.

Comment: As I wrote, there are thousands of Android device models, containing dozens, if not hundreds, of distinct apps that might be considered a "gallery". Few will be whatever "Gallery" app you are looking at. Not all will offer filters, publicizing of filter settings to third-party apps, etc.